# Simplifying RegionUnion call after CylindricalDecomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-manipulation, boolean-computation

I want to simplify unions of output from `CylindricalDecomposition` calls.

Consider:

```
decomp1 = CylindricalDecomposition[x > y && y >= 0, {x, y}]
decomp2 = CylindricalDecomposition[y >= x && x >= 0, {x, y}]
```

These yield, respectively:

```
x > 0 && 0 <= y < x
x >= 0 && y >= x
```

Pen and paper shows that their union is `x >= 0 && y >= 0`.  What Mathematica call returns this?

Unsuccessful attempts:

1. `Union[decomp1, decomp2]` yields `x > 0 && x >= 0 && y >= x && 0 <= y < x`.
2. `RegionUnion[decomp1, decomp2]` yields `RegionUnion::reg: x>0&&0<=y<x is not a correctly specified region`.
3. `RegionUnion[ImplicitRegion[decomp1, {x, y}], ImplicitRegion[decomp2, {x, y}]]` yields `ImplicitRegion[(x > 0 && 0 <= y < x) || (x >= 0 && y >= x), {x, y}]`.

Comment: `Reduce[decomp1 || decomp2]` or directly `Reduce[(x > y && y >= 0) || (y >= x && x >= 0)]`.

Comment: thanks @MarcoB - if you set this as an answer, I'd be glad to accept it.  I'm ultimately interested in larger systems (q.v. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263788/showing-that-cylindricaldecomposition-returns-partition-the-space), where this doesn't seem to simplify: are there extra steps I can take to simplify such systems further?